# Unable to set cookie

Tags: php, cookies, laravel-5

Even though there is no error returned, the following logic does not set any cookie.

```
<?php
namespace App\Libraries;

use Cookie;
use Location;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class GeoLocation
{
    public $request;
    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function getLocationByIP()
    {
        $location = Location::get();
        // Get the location by city
        return $location->cityName;
    }

    public function getLocation()
    {
        // Check if the location is already set in the cookie
        if ($this->request->cookie('location')) {
            return $this->request->cookie('location');
        } else {
            $location = $this->getLocationByIP();
            // Set location in the cookie
            Cookie::queue('location', $location, 1440);
            return $location;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: debugging: `var_dump($this->request->cookie('location'), __FILE__.__LINE__);` as the first line in: `function getLocation()`. Also: `var_dump($('location', __FILE__.__LINE__),` immediately before the `return $location;`. It will tell you whether the current value and if the cookie is being set.

Comment: oops: replace `'location'` with `$location` so you can see the value.